# SonarQube - limit scanned files to compiled files

Tags: sonarqube

I am scanning my c++ project with build_wrapper and sonar-scanner.

the scan ends well but for some reason the amount of files that are checked is larger then the files that are participating in the compilation.

files that are unit test are also scanned if they are in the same folder.

is it possible to limit to check only compiled files?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

<sonar.exclusions> yourdirectory/specific.file, yourdirectory/*.cpp </sonar.exclusions>

or using the sonar.properties sonar.exclusions=yourdirectory/specific.file, yourdirectory/*.cpp

Comment: thanks for the answer , but I don't want to do it manually. I want to be by compiled code. if I use includes/excludes I will have to manage it every time.